# Telegram - бот, меняющий био пользователя

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, aiogram

Всем привет, я начинающий кодер ботов в телеграм, хочу написать код, в котором бот сможет взаимодействовать с информацией о пользователе(О себе) и сможет писать в ней любую информацию, со ссылками в тексте и тд, возможно ли это и если и возможно, то с помощью какой функции и какой библиотеки?